# How to loop through consecutive lines in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, file, text

I have a text file that, for the sake of simplicity, contains:

```
cat
dog
goat
giraffe
walrus
elephant
```

How can I create a script that would set a variable, animal in this case, to the first line in the text file, print animal, but then do the whole thing again, but make animal set to the next line (in this instance, dog).

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
while True:
    with open('./text.txt','r') as f:
        for i in enumerate('./text.txt'):
            if i in lines:
                print(lines)
```

Comment: Do you mean line or next word?

Comment: Though I don't understand what you want to do, but I'm pretty sure you should change your for loop to: `for index, line in enumerate(f):` `if line in lines:` `print(line)`

Comment: Your code doesn't match what you're trying to do at all. What *are* you trying to do - just print each line of the file one at a time?

Comment: `for line in f:` will iterate through the lines of a file. Note there will be a newline at the end of each one, so you'll probably want to have a `line = line.rstrip()` before comparing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read the file one line at a time (which may be needed for large files):

```
with open('./text.txt','r') as f:
    line = True
    # this will stop when there is nothing left to read, as line will be ''
    # note that an 'empty' line will still have a line ending, i.e. '\n'
    while line:
        line = f.readline()
        print(line)
```

If you don't care about the size, you can read all lines at once with `.readlines()` and just loop over the returned values from that.

Comment: Just what I was looking for, and yes, it's a large file. Thanks a million!!

Answer (score 0):

Use readlines to store each line in a list.

```py
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    animals = f.readlines()

for animal in animals:
    print(animal.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
with open('./text.txt') as f:
    for animal in f.readlines():
        print(animal.strip())
```

Comment: `readline()` will only return the first line and `animal` will iterate over the characters in `'cat\n'`.

Comment: The edit fixes the problem, but now the answer is identical to @sarthak's earlier answer, with the `animals` intermediate variable removed (which I assumed was only there to make it explicit that all content is loaded at once.